# how to apply repeatedly css3 transform to div element

Tags: jquery, css, transform

I have a div that I am applying css3 transform to move it to the right (adding the move class to it) and left (removing the move class from). After adding the move class to make my div (id=container) to move to the right, I wanna be able to make the div more again to the right after adding the move class for the second time. Move class is added or removed with jquery when buttons "Move right" and "Move left" are respectively clicked.

here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#bMoveRight').on('click', function(e){
            $('#container').addClass('move');
        });

        $('#bMoveLeft').on('click', function(e){
            $('#container').removeClass('move');
        });
    });     
    </script>
    <style>
    #container{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:red;
        box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #000;
        word-wrap:break-word;
        transition: translateX 2s;
        -webkit-transition: translateX 2s;
    }

    .move{
        transform: translateX(100px);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
    }
    </style>
        </head> (should match the opening <head> tag, omitted due to restraints on the posting)
            <body>
<div id="container">This is a good testing container that I hope will behave itself</div>
<p><button id="bMoveLeft">Move left</button>
<button id="bMoveRight">Move right</button></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to apply the same class twice to one element. What you can do instead is check to see what class is currently applied to the element, and then apply the correct transform class (move2, move3, etc.) which each have larger and larger translate properties:

```
.move2 {
    transform: translateX(200px);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your reply, I got what I wanted by tweaking a bit your idea. I dropped the css class and apply the transform on the fly using jquery. My code now looks like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var count = 0;
        $('#bMoveRight').on('click', function(e){
            ++count;
            $('#container').css('-webkit-transform', 'translateX(' + count + '00px)');
        });

        $('#bMoveLeft').on('click', function(e){
            --count;
            $('#container').css('-webkit-transform', 'translateX(' + count + '00px)');
        });
    });     
    </script>
    <style>
    #container{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:red;
        box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #000;
        word-wrap:break-word;
        transition: transform 2s;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s;
    }
    </style>

            <body>
        <div id="container">This is a good testing container that I hope will behave itself</div>
        <p><button id="bMoveLeft">Move left</button>
        <button id="bMoveRight">Move right</button></p>
  </body>
```